# On premises Active Directory to Azure Sync with spaces in username

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I've been asked to sync our corporate on premises AD that I have inherited with Azure using the AD connector, but lsFX.exe has reported two types of errors that I need to overcome.

The first is that the AD is running on .local which gives a topleveldomain error. So I've added a fully qualified UPN suffix to AD, so I think I've overcome that one.

The second error is that the username have been previously set up with spaces such as job blogs instead of joe.blogs and this is kicking off an error for every user.

Internally it's going to be difficult to get everyone's username changes do to integration with other applications such as on premises TFS. I tried changing one user by adding a . in place of the space and TFS saw them as a different user and started a cascade of other issues.

Does anyone know if AD Azure allows usernames to have spaces joe blogs@thedomain.com so I can ignore the error, or some way around this issue?

Comment: I don't think they allows spaces: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-passwords-policy#userprincipalname-policies-that-apply-to-all-user-accounts

Comment: Thank you. That article with username/password restrictions if very useful in showing that spaces in usernames are not allowed so I cannot ignore this error.  The next part of the question therefore is what are my options to move forward and how to sort this out.